# Application scope view model for view attached to WindowManager

Tags: android, scope, viewmodel, window-managers

We have a view which is added to WindowManager so that it is always visible even when the activities change.

- This code is in a library so multiple applications can use it.
- The view is a typical view extending a layout and view a setting for state.
- We can successfully get it to run as either a service or directly to WindowManager.
- We created a viewmodel to consume data and provide a state for the UI to render.

There is a debate about weither or not to use a "ViewModel"

- On one side we can say that the view shows ui and the viewmodel provides state. The application and usage of it's scope is application implementation separate of the these. In this case the view model would have to be scoped to application to match the usage of the WindowManager
- On the other hand documentation states that view model should be scoped to activity, fragments, and other lifecycle aware. The benefit of a viewmodel is not really there because it equates to a singleton.

There's lots more to discuss about both sides. Wondering if there is any official approach defined for providing data to the ui when the ui is attached to WindowManager?